# Problem: implement an ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04) on an FPGA (DE1-SOC)

Tags: vhdl, sensors, led, quartus, intel-fpga

My goal is to implement an ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04) on my FPGA(DE1-SOC) so that the values of my LEDs evolve according to the distance of an obstacle.

I'm working on QUARTUS II in VHDL. The problem I have is that no LEDs light up when I upload to my card.

I have my code which is the following:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity SENSOR is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;

        trig : out std_logic;
        echo : in  std_logic;

        LEDR : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
end entity SENSOR;

architecture rtl of SENSOR is
    signal tick_us : std_logic;
    signal tick_us_ctr : integer range 0 to 50;

    signal trig_ctr : integer range 0 to 60_010;
    
    signal echo_width_us : integer range 0 to 40_000;
    signal out_range : std_logic :='0'; -- verifie depassement 40 ms de echo_width_us 
begin
    gen_tick_us : process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            tick_us_ctr <= 0;
            tick_us <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if tick_us_ctr >= 50-1 then
                tick_us <= '1';
                tick_us_ctr <= 0;
            else
                tick_us <= '0';
                tick_us_ctr <= tick_us_ctr + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    gen_trig : process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            trig <= '0';
            trig_ctr <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) and tick_us = '1' then -- every 1 us
            if trig_ctr >= 60_010-1 then -- 60 ms + 10 us
                trig <= '0';
                trig_ctr <= 0;
            elsif trig_ctr = 60_000-1 then -- 60 ms
                trig <= '1';
                trig_ctr <= trig_ctr + 1;
            else
                trig_ctr <= trig_ctr + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    measure_width : process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            echo_width_us <= 0;
            LEDR <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) and tick_us = '1' then -- every 1 us
            if echo = '1' then
                if echo_width_us < 40_001 then
                    echo_width_us <= echo_width_us + 1;
                else
                    out_range <= '1';
                end if;
            elsif echo = '0' and echo_width_us > 0 then
                if out_range ='1' then 
                    echo_width_us <= 0;
                    out_range <= '0';
                    LEDR <= (others => '0');
                else
                    echo_width_us <= 0;
                    LEDR <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(echo_width_us / 58, 10));
                    --ledr <= (others => '0');
                    --ledr() >= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

I know that this one works because I tested it on ModelSim by making my TestBench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity SENSOR_TestBench is
end entity SENSOR_TestBench;

architecture rtl of SENSOR_TestBench is
    signal clk_50 : std_logic;
    signal rst    : std_logic;
    
    signal trig : std_logic;
    signal echo : std_logic;
    
    signal ledr : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
begin
    uut : entity work.SENSOR
        port map (
            clk => clk_50,
            rst => rst,
            
            trig => trig,
            echo => echo,
            
            ledr => ledr
        );
    
    clk_rst : process
    begin
        rst <= '1';
        clk_50 <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        rst <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        
        for i in 0 to 50 * 1000 * 1000 loop
            clk_50 <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns;
            
            clk_50 <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
    end process;
    
    process
    begin
        echo <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        
        wait until trig = '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        echo <= '1';
        wait for 5 ms;
        echo <= '0';
        
        wait until trig = '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        echo <= '1';
        wait for 10 ms;
        echo <= '0';
        
        wait until trig = '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        echo <= '1';
        wait for 25 ms;
        echo <= '0';
        
        wait until trig = '1';
        wait for 10 us;
        echo <= '1';
        wait for 50 ms;
        echo <= '0';
        
    end process;
end architecture;
```

[Simu ModelSim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceeco.png)

I don't think this is a PINs mapping problem either, I respected the user manual of the card:

[Mapping PINs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7Fr.png)

I'm starting on QUARTUS II so I think I may have forgotten a step by uploading my code in my card:

[Programmer Quartus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYz83.png)

I also tested my ultrasonic sensor on my Raspberry to see if it was not faulty but it works well:

[Test Ultrasonic sensor on Raspberry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdcvJ.jpg)

I don't know what to do anymore, if someone has an idea, I take it all :D

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have it powered by 5V?

Comment: When running the testbench process `measure_width` the evaluation `if echo_width_us < 40_001 then` results in a bounds check violation during simulation. That should be `40_000` or the range of  `echo_width_us` should be greater. (The counter would appears to saturate over around 280 ms).

Comment: @user1155120 No it's not powered in 5V, how do I do on quartus for this to be the case?

Comment: @BrianDrummond My question is how do I put my code on the card? I feel like I forgot a step on quartus because when I upload, no LEDs light up :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure of what you're doing with Quartus. I suggest you start with a simple clock divider (ie a large counter) and assign the MSB to the output led.
Once you see the led toggling, you'll know your implementation steps are corrects as well as your programming step.
Afterward, you may go back to your specific sensor module.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try to do that first, thanks for your answer !

Comment: This answer si a good start : you can simplify it further if the board has a switch and a LED : mock up a design that connects the switch to the LED. Getting that through the tools and writing a constraint file for the switch and LED pins puts you in a stronger position for this exercise and then the real design.

Comment: Another thing. Are you sure of the reset active level state? I see your code is active high. My guess it might active low and so your design is stuck in reset state. Also, did you check the pins assigned to all IOs of your design? For instance, what are the pins for reset and clock?